# From where does the date in GETDATE() function comes from?

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

Does Anyone know from where `GETDATE()` gets the `DATE` itself?

Comment: From the server.

Comment: if i using localhost as server, is that mean getdate use my localhost date as the date?

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql `Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running`

Comment: thanks dude , thats help me a lot @Squirrel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good Question.

The `GETDATE()` function get the `DATETIME` from the `server` which is connect.

If you connect you `localhost` then get it from your local machine.

Otherwise you connect any server, it get the `DATETIME` from the `SERVER` you are connect.

Hope this helps you:

You can use `DATEADD` function:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,3,GETDATE())
```

Comment: thanks for answer bro. but one more question still buzzing in my head hahaha, is there any possibilities if i set date on my computer to 3 day further and my program which use localhost as server and it run GETDATE() , read the date+3 as the current date?